# Commands to do things like alt-tab

Tags: metacity

Are there commands to preform actions such as alt-tab?

Comment: I'm afraid I don't quite understand what you mean by "commands to perform actions." Do you mean other shortcuts to manage open windows?

Comment: A command from the shell? But if you are in a shell, and do 1 times 'alt tab', you're in a second application, if there is any - if you do it two times, the second command can't be issued, because now you already switched away. :)

Comment: I'm actually trying to bind things to a gesture application. I'm not actually planing on typing them out in terminal every time I want to show the desktop or switch windows or whatever.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Given you last comment Alexander, I think you want to use "xte" which is available if you install the xautomation software package from software centre or synaptic manager

'xte' is a command line tool which you could shell out from your code.

Example syntax to invoke an "ALT-TAB" would be

```
xte "keydown Alt_L" "key Tab" "keyup Alt_L"
```

Comment: Thanks. I started using xsendkeys, but this looks more useful since it can also hold keys down. Thanks!